# A comma or a semicolon?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, commas, semicolons

Which is grammatically correct?

> a. Sue enjoyed the lunch at Jamey's restaurant : eating two portions of rice and cheese.
>
> b. Sue enjoyed the lunch at Jamey's restaurant ; eating two portions of rice and cheese.
>
> c. Sue enjoyed the lunch at Jamey's restaurant , eating two portions of rice and cheese.

Note, the sentence is the exact same, except for the punctuation, do I need to punt a colon or semicolon  or a comma ?

Comment: "Sue" is a name, and needs a capital letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"eating two portions of rice and cheese" is a participial phrase. According to [this reference](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/participlephrase.htm), no punctuation is required when a participial phrase follows a main clause, although I think it works better with a comma in this case.

You would only use a colon or a semi-colon if the second part contained a verb, for example with **ate** in this sentence:

> Sue enjoyed the lunch at Jamey's restaurant: she **ate** two portions of rice and cheese.

Here is more information about using [semicolons](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/semicolon.html) and [colons](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/colon.html).